# Google Forms Script to open form on specific times on weekdays & weekends

Tags: forms, scripting

I am using the following script to have the form available between 6am & 8am every day, however, I'd like it to be available 6am-8am on weekdays & 6am-11am on weekends... Suggestions?

```
function initTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('oc').timeBased().atHour(0).everyDays(1).create();
}

function oc() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(function(e){
    if(e.getHandlerFunction() == "openForm" || e.getHandlerFunction() == "closeForm") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(e)
    }
  });

  var time = new Date()
  time.setHours(6);
  time.setMinutes(00);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm").timeBased().at(time).create();

  time.setHours(8);
  time.setMinutes(0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm").timeBased().at(time).create();
}

function openForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

function closeForm() {  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  // deleteTriggers_();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any details of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm not a developer... Just trying to find a fix for a script I found. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it to work with the following:

```
function initTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('oc').timeBased().atHour(0).everyDays(1).create();
}

function oc() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(function(e){
    if(e.getHandlerFunction() == "openForm" || e.getHandlerFunction() == "closeForm") {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(e)
    }
  });

  var day = new Date();
  if (day.getDay()>5 || day.getDay()==0) {

  var time = new Date()
  time.setHours(6);
  time.setMinutes(00);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm").timeBased().at(time).create();

  time.setHours(11);
  time.setMinutes(00);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm").timeBased().at(time).create();
}

else {

  var time = new Date()
  time.setHours(6);
  time.setMinutes(00);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("openForm").timeBased().at(time).create();

  time.setHours(8);
  time.setMinutes(00);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("closeForm").timeBased().at(time).create();

     }
}

function openForm() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

function closeForm() {  
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  // deleteTriggers_();
}
```